# Scroll Trigger not working with a forEach() method - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, scroll, dom-events

I've done a simple scroll trigger that applies an animation when an element goes past 70% of the viewport height. Whilst working out how to do this I used a single element and `querySelector` and it all works fine.

Now that I'm testing on multiple elements I changed the code to `querySelectorAll` and therefore need to use a `forEach` method with a forEach variable `item`.  I cannot for the life of me get it to trigger with the `forEach` method though?

Any help would be awesome.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/pauljohnknight/pen/eywyyP

P.S I forked the Codepen here https://codepen.io/pauljohnknight/pen/xpojao to show how it works with the single `querySelector` div if you need to see the intended behaviour

JS

```
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

function scrollTrigger() {

  var boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var boxPositionPercent = (boxPosition / window.innerHeight) * 100;

    console.log(boxPositionPercent);

    box.forEach(function(item){
      if (boxPositionPercent <= 70) {
            item.classList.add('scroll-active')
          } else {
            item.classList.remove('scroll-active')
          }
     });
 }

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollTrigger);
```

CSS

```
body {margin:0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 300vh; display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;}

.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 50px; 
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: .1;
  margin-bottom: 30px;}

.scroll-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I see `TypeError: box.getBoundingClientRect is not a function` error in the console when running the codepen.

Comment: Why don't you use jquery?

Comment: var boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top; this is the problem when you have an array of elements

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is returning an array of elements, but you expect a single element. Below I've moved your `boxPosition` code inside the forEach. Try [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXZzRB).

```
function scrollTrigger() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

    boxes.forEach(function(box){
        var boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var boxPositionPercent = (boxPosition / window.innerHeight) * 100;
        console.log(boxPositionPercent);

        if (boxPositionPercent <= 70) {
            box.classList.add('scroll-active')
        } else {
            box.classList.remove('scroll-active')
        }
   });
 }

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollTrigger);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to get the offset top of an array, you need to get the offset top of each element, so, you just need to put the variables `boxPosition` and `box PositionPercent` inside de forEach, and change `box.getBoudingClientRect().top` to `item.getBoundingClientRect().top`, like this:

[example](https://codepen.io/spacedog4/pen/MrMXbd)

```
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

function scrollTrigger() {

  box.forEach(function(item){
    var boxPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var boxPositionPercent = (boxPosition / window.innerHeight) * 100;
      if (boxPositionPercent <= 70) {
            item.classList.add('scroll-active')
          } else {
            item.classList.remove('scroll-active')
          }
     });

 }

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollTrigger);
```